# Javascript new Map() structure on mobile device does it work?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mobile

I wrote some code in javascript using Map(), it works well on the pc browsers, but on the mobile device it is not working?

I am testing in Android 4.4.2

I checked this page
http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Map
it is not supported on Android 4.4.2,

What could be the solution? 
What are the alternatives?

Comment: I think you have to be more specific about your mobile platform you've used for testing. You can check the **Map**'s support here: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Map (Scroll down and you will find Map)

Comment: thanks #LS05, I checked the page it is not supported on Android 4.4, I have to find another data structure, I was searching for such a page but couldn't find it, thanks again

Comment: Maybe there's a solution about using ES6 on legacy Javascript engines. See: https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/